# What set of $n$ allows uniform distribution of points on a sphere where all points are equidistant to their nearest neighbors?

Tags: geometry

I know the platonic configurations are one set of $n$ that are equidistant, as well as n=2.  I can imagine, but not prove, that there is a configuration when n=3.

There is apparently a series I do not know which allows, for example, 30 points to be equidistant (like the d20 in D&D), but probably not 31.  Is it boundless?

Comment: What does neighbors mean in this context? Is there any reason you can't place all the points on a single equator?

Comment: It means on any axis, without privilege.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: That isn't clear at all.  How are the vertices of a regular solid "on any axis, without privilege."?

Comment: Distances are measured along a maximum circumference or euclidean distance?

Comment: Perhaps the question is poorly posed, yet  I know exactly what I mean.  I think maximum circumference is probably closer to what I mean.

Comment: [Geodesic polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_polyhedron)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9600801/5802041

Comment: "I know exactly what I mean." Well good for you I guess. Can you explain why equally spaced points on the equator do not satisfy your criteria? In that configuration, all points have the same distance to their nearest neighbours.

Comment: Anyway, consider https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiregular_polyhedron

Comment: @JeanMarie That question does not require uniform distance between points.

Comment: @Rahul:  I've edited the question.  The issue is uniformity, yet to describe that precisely gives me a headache.

Comment: @79037662:  I re-worded the question (yet again, sorry);

Comment: You are just changing the peripheral parts of the question without clarifying the main issue that everyone is asking about. What is "uniformity"? What do you mean by a "uniform distribution of points"? Even an informal, intuitive explanation of what you are looking for would shed some light.